# How to build and distribute iOS debug build?

Tags: ios, xcode

If I need to distribute iOS release build I create ipa file via [Product -> Archive] and then distribute it. But I don't know how to distribute version for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same flow with the Archive. Just change the Build Configuration for the Archive action.

1. Open the scheme settings (`CMD` + `Shift` + `.`)
2. Select the Archive action
3. Change the Build Configuration to the Debug
4. Archive the build

[image]